# How can I improve the response speed of request with a projection in Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a goal repository that returns a list Goals based on a competition:

```
public interface GoalRespository extends JpaRepository<Goal,Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM goal g " +
            "JOIN matches m ON g.goal_match = m.idmatch " +
            "JOIN competitions c ON m.competition = c.idcompetitions " +
            "WHERE c.idcompetitions = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Goal> findGoalsByCompetition(@Param ("competition") Long competition);

}
```

And then I have a Projection for my Goal Class that return the Player that scored the goal inline:

```
@Projection(name = "goalInlinePlayers", types = { Goal.class })
public interface GoalInlinePlayers {

    Long getIdgoal();
    Long getGoalMinute();
    Long getGoalSeconds();
    Player getGoalPlayer();
}
```

So my problem is that if I do a GET call to the endpoint without the projection

> /goals/search/findGoalsByCompetition?competition=219

the response takes lest than a second, if I add the projection to my query params

> /goals/search/findGoalsByCompetition?competition=219&projection=goalInlinePlayers

It takes around 12 seconds to resolve. 
Also, for some display purposes I need to add assists and teams to my projection, in which case it takes 20 seconds.

**Some extra data:**

- The example that takes that time has 350 goals.
- I have the exact same thing to return matches from a competition with a projection to inline the home and away team objects and it takes 1.5 seconds.
- The teams table have 150 records while the players table have around 2000. (Not sure if related)

Any thoughts on why is it taking so long to resolve a request with a projection or where is the bottleneck?

Comment: Check the SQL logs and see what queries are being executed.

Comment: **hibernate.show_sql=true** and you will see sql queries

Comment: @AndrewNepogoda I managed to find the problem. Spring queries the DB for each object and stores it, so if it has to query again for the same object it already has it. That is why when I ask for "Teams" in matches, it is fast because querying for 10 or 500 matches is the same because it only asks the database for 20 teams once. Goals is slow because there are many different scorers so instead of 20 teams, requests 200 players and there is the diff. I guess projections is not gonna help me out with this one

Comment: @MatiasDiez take a look at spring data specification (JpaSpecificationExecutor interface for repositories). It can help you to implement query with filters instead of projection. Link: https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/

Comment: And if you share your db model (entities with relations) probably I can help you.